# Effect of LP order and sampling frequency on formants of speech

Tags: signal-processing, speech, mfcc, lpc

I have been trying to understand linear prediction of speech. I came to know that the order p of the LP predictor should be (Fs/1000)+2. In case of a 8KHz speech signal, the LP spectrum will range from 0 to 4KHz, and there will be 4 to 5 peaks corresponding to each formant. Does that mean, in case of a 16KHz speech signal, the LP spectrum will range from 0 to 8KHz and there will be 8 formants, because of 8 peaks?
The second doubt I have is that the value of formant frequencies in case of a 8KHz speech signal will be limited to 4KHz only, while for 16KHz, we will get higher values of formant frequencies? What am I missing in my understanding?

Comment: Most of a speech signal energy is below 4kHz. So you may have additional peaks between 4-8kHz, but their amplitude will be lower than those from the 0 to 4kHz range (and have a generally lower impact on the linear prediction coefficients).

Answer (score 1):

The number of poles will be equal to the order of the linear predictor system. However some of these poles will be on the real axis (frequency zero) and are not considered as formant candidates (these model the spectral slope of the voice and why the order is often higher than the number of desired formants). Poles with an imaginary part will always have a complex conjugate partner. One formant will correspond to each of these pairs.

The maximum formant will be `F_s/2`

You should have a play with Praat and their formant estimation changing the maximum formant frequency and the number of formants. You really have to chose the maximum formant (sampling rate) and number of formants (order) correctly, or else praat will estimate a only a single formant in between the first and second, or second and third formant. Formant estimation by LPC is not very rubust to bad choices of these parameters, in my expirence.

[image]